# Array of strings Group by first common letters

Tags: ruby

Is there anyway of grouping first common letters in an array of strings?

For example:

```
 array = [ 'hello', 'hello you', 'people', 'finally', 'finland' ]
```

so when i  do

```
array.group_by{ |string| some_logic_with_string }
```

The result should be,

```
{ 
   'hello' => ['hello', 'hello you'],
   'people' => ['people'],
   'fin' => ['finally', 'finland']
}
```

Comment: Your logic is not clear. What is the expected result for `array = ["a", "ab", "abc"]`?

Comment: The way it's phrased is a bit ambiguous. If you wanted to group by first `n` characters, that's trivial: `array.group_by { a[0...n] }`, but not sure this is what you're after.

Comment: What about `['aba', 'abb', 'aaa', 'aab']`?

Comment: @Drenmi It is clear that that is not the case. Look at the keys in the OP's expected hash. Do they all have the same length?

Comment: What is the expected result when the array is `["Why", "haven't", "you", "answered", "the", "above", "questions?", "Please", "do", "so."] `.

Comment: Well, considering `array = ['a', 'ab', 'abc']`, the result can be `{ 'a' => ['a'], 'ab' => ['ab', 'abc'] }`, for ['aba', 'abb', 'aaa', 'aab'] -> `{ 'ab' => ['aba', 'abb'], 'aa' = >['aaa', 'aab'] }` and for 
`["Why", "haven't", "you", "answered", "the", "above", "questions?", "Please", "do", "so."]` -> `{'W' => ['Why'], 'h' => ['haven't'], 'y' => ['you'], 'a' => ['answered', 'above'], 't' => ['the'], 'q' => ['questions?'], 'P' => ['Please'] 'd' => ['do'], 's' => ['so'] }`

Comment: For `array = ['a', 'ab', 'abc']`, why is it not `{'a' => ['a', 'ab', 'abc']}` or `{'a' => ['a', 'ab'], 'abc' => ['abc']}`, etc?

Comment: I think your expected output is bit flawed - Why do you expect `'people' => ['people']`, in one example, and expect `'W' => ['Why']` in the above comment - it should be `"Why"=>["Why"]`.

Comment: Programming is all about being precise, in your thinking and words as well as your coding. Before posting a question you need to review it carefully for completeness and precision. Most of all, you need to be demanding of yourself. The fundamental problem is not that the question is ambiguous, it's that you didn't realize it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE: Some test cases are ambiguous and expectations conflict with other tests, you need to fix them**.

---

I guess plain `group_by` may not work, a further processing is needed.

I have come up with below code that seems to work for all the given test cases in consistent manner.

I have left notes in the code to explain the logic.  Only way to fully understand it will be to inspect value of `h` and see the flow for a simple test case.

```
def group_by_common_chars(array)
    # We will iteratively group by as many time as there are characters
    # in a largest possible key, which is max length of all strings
    max_len = array.max_by {|i| i.size}.size

    # First group by first character.
    h = array.group_by{|i| i[0]}

    # Now iterate remaining (max_len - 1) times
    (1...max_len).each do |c|
        # Let's perform a group by next set of starting characters.
        t = h.map do |k,v|
            h1 = v.group_by {|i| i[0..c]} 
        end.reduce(&:merge)

        # We need to merge the previously generated hash
        # with the hash generated in this iteration.  Here things get tricky.
        # If previously, we had 
        #    {"a" => ["a"], "ab" => ["ab", "abc"]},
        # and now, we have 
        #    {"a"=>["a"], "ab"=>["ab"], "abc"=>["abc"]},
        # We need to merge the two hashes such that we have
        #    {"a"=>["a"], "ab"=>["ab", "abc"], "abc"=>["abc"]}.
        # Note that `Hash#merge`'s block is called only for common keys, so, "abc"
        # will get merged, we can't do much about it now.  We will process
        # it later in the loop    
        h = h.merge(t) do |k, o, n| 
            if (o.size != n.size)
                diff = [o,n].max - [o,n].min
                if diff.size == 1 && t.value?(diff)
                    [o,n].max
                else
                    [o,n].min
                end
            else
                o
            end
        end
    end

    # Sort by key length, smallest in the beginning.
    h = h.sort {|i,j| i.first.size <=> j.first.size }.to_h

    # Get rid of those key-value pairs, where value is single element array
    # and that single element is already part of another key-value pair, and
    # that value array has more than one element.  This step will allow us
    # to get rid of key-value like "abc"=>["abc"] in the example discussed
    # above.

    h = h.tap do |h|
        keys = h.keys
        keys.each do |k|
            v = h[k]    
            if (v.size == 1 && 
                h.key?(v.first) && 
                h.values.flatten.count(v.first) > 1) then
                h.delete(k)
            end
        end
    end

    # Get rid of those keys whose value array consist of only elements that
    # already part of some other key.  Since, hash is ordered by key's string 
    # size, this process allows us to get rid of those keys which are smaller 
    # in length but consists of only elements that are present somewhere else
    # with a key of larger length.  For example, it lets us to get rid of 
    # "a"=>["aba", "abb", "aaa", "aab"] from a hash like
    # {"a"=>["aba", "abb", "aaa", "aab"], "ab"=>["aba", "abb"], "aa"=>["aaa", "aab"]}
    h.tap do |h|
        keys = h.keys
        keys.each do |k|
            values = h[k]
            other_values = h.values_at(*(h.keys-[k])).flatten
            already_present = values.all? do |v|
                other_values.include?(v)
            end
            h.delete(k) if already_present
        end
    end
end
```

Sample Run:

```
p group_by_common_chars ['hello', 'hello you', 'people', 'finally', 'finland']
#=> {"fin"=>["finally", "finland"], "hello"=>["hello", "hello you"], "people"=>["people"]}

p group_by_common_chars ['a', 'ab', 'abc']
#=> {"a"=>["a"], "ab"=>["ab", "abc"]}

p group_by_common_chars  ['aba', 'abb', 'aaa', 'aab']
#=> {"ab"=>["aba", "abb"], "aa"=>["aaa", "aab"]}

p group_by_common_chars ["Why", "haven't", "you", "answered", "the", "above", "questions?", "Please", "do", "so."]
#=> {"a"=>["answered", "above"], "do"=>["do"], "Why"=>["Why"], "you"=>["you"], "so."=>["so."], "the"=>["the"], "Please"=>["Please"], "haven't"=>["haven't"], "questions?"=>["questions?"]}
```

Comment: `@Wand Maker` Really Awesome. This is what i want. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure, if you can sort by all common letters. But if you want to do sort only by first letter then here it is:

```
array = [ 'hello', 'hello you', 'people', 'finally', 'finland' ]    
result = {}
array.each { |st| result[st[0]] = result.fetch(st[0], []) + [st] }

pp result
{"h"=>["hello", "hello you"], "p"=>["people"], "f"=>["finally", "finland"]}
```

Now `result` contains your desired hash.

Comment: That is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yes, I know that. And I wrote that in first line.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, you're trying to do something that's pretty custom. I can think of two classical approaches that sort of do what you want: 1) [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and 2) [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

With stemming you're finding the root word to a longer word. Here's a [gem](https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer) for it.

Levenshtein is a famous algorithm which calculates the difference between two strings. There is a [gem](https://github.com/dbalatero/levenshtein-ffi) for it that runs pretty fast due to a native C extension.